# JAVA code to use semaphore with Cassandra to throttle executeAsync writes to eliminate NoHostAvailableException errors

Tags: java, cassandra, semaphore, datastax-java-driver

I have some basic code that uses a prepared statement in a for loop and writes the result into a Cassandra Table with some throttling using a semaphore.

```
  Session session = null;
  try {
    session = connector.openSession();
  } catch( Exception ex ) {
    //  .. moan and complain..
    System.err.printf("Got %s trying to openSession - %s\n", ex.getClass().getCanonicalName(), ex.getMessage() );
  }
  if( session != null ) {

// Prepared Statement for Cassandra Inserts
        PreparedStatement statement = session.prepare(
                                "INSERT INTO model.base " +
                                "(channel, " +
                                "time_key, " +
                                "power" +
                                ") VALUES (?,?,?);");
        BoundStatement boundStatement = new BoundStatement(statement); 


//Query Cassandra Table that has capital letters in the column names        
        ResultSet results = session.execute("SELECT \"Time_Key\",\"Power\",\"Bandwidth\",\"Start_Frequency\" FROM \"SB1000_49552019\".\"Measured_Value\" limit 800000;");

 // Get the Variables from each Row of Cassandra Data        
       for (Row row : results){
           // Upper Case Column Names in Cassandra
           time_key = row.getLong("Time_Key");
           start_frequency = row.getDouble("Start_Frequency");
           power = row.getFloat("Power");
           bandwidth = row.getDouble("Bandwidth");


// Create Channel Power Buckets, place information into prepared statement binding, write to cassandra.
                for(channel = 1.6000E8; channel <= channel_end; channel+=increment ){       
                    if( (channel >= start_frequency) && (channel <= (start_frequency + bandwidth)) ) {

                  ResultSetFuture rsf =  session.executeAsync(boundStatement.bind(channel,time_key,power));  
                       backlogList.add( rsf );   // put the new one at the end of the list
                       if( backlogList.size() > 10000 ) {      // wait till we have a few

                           while( backlogList.size() > 5432 ) {      // then harvest about half of the oldest ones of them

                               rsf = backlogList.remove(0);

                               rsf.getUninterruptibly();

                           }    // end while

                       }  // end if

                    }  // end if

                }  // end for

  } // end "row" for

 } // end session
```

My connection is built with the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
if (args.length != 2) {
    System.err.println("Syntax: com.neutronis.Spark_Reports <Spark Master URL> <Cassandra contact point>");
    System.exit(1);
}

SparkConf conf = new SparkConf();
conf.setAppName("Spark Reports");
conf.setMaster(args[0]);
conf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", args[1]);

Spark_Reports app = new Spark_Reports(conf);

app.run();
}
```

With this code im attempting to use a semaphore but my Cassandra Cluster still seems to get overloaded and kick out the error:

> ERROR ControlConnection: [Control connection] Cannot connect to any
>   host, scheduling retry in 1000 milliseconds Exception in thread "main"
>   com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All
>   host(s) tried for query failed (no host was tried)

It seems odd that it says no host was tried.

I've looked at other semaphore throttling issues such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30509095/cassandra-is-there-a-way-to-limit-number-of-async-queries) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35323856/what-is-the-best-way-to-get-backpressure-for-cassandra-writes/35327397#35327397) and attempted to apply to my code above but am still getting the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read my answer to this question for how to back-pressure when using asynchronous calls: [What is the best way to get backpressure for Cassandra Writes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35323856/what-is-the-best-way-to-get-backpressure-for-cassandra-writes/35327397#35327397)

Comment: I see the article and it appears interesting do you have some reference code for a visual guide to follow for implementation?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I've seen this pattern implemented many times on some projects but their source code is not open-sourced :(